# htaccess using QSA returning 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, qsa

I'm trying to direct a url for a blog post to a PHP page that takes a GET var using htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/post/(\w+)$ blog/post.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However, this just gives me a 404. I have confirmed that `/blog/post.php?title=my-post`is a valid url.

Comment: Where is your htaccess located?

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^blog/post/([\w-]+)$ blog/post.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]` as you have hyphen in title

Comment: @anubhava - That was it. Submit an answer if you want the credit :)

Comment: @starkeen - It is located in the root of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your title contains hyphens your rule should allow it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/post/([\w-]+)$ blog/post.php?title=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```